# Pull-Up resistor for a 74LVC1G06 Inverter

Tags: resistors, inverter, pullup, hdmi

As part of dual mode display port design, Pin13 goes to [74LVC1G06](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G06.pdf) inverter input (see U89):

[image]

in case where I want to choose only HDMI I need to connect a pull-up to *DP_0_PIN13*.

from wikipedia : "Limited adapter speed – Although the pinout and digital signal values transmitted by the DP port are identical to a native DVI/HDMI source, the signals are transmitted at DisplayPort's native voltage (3.3 V) instead of the 5 V used by DVI and HDMI. As a result, dual-mode adapters must contain a level-shifter circuit which changes the voltage. The presence of this circuit places a limit on how quickly the adapter can operate, and therefore newer adapters are required for each higher speed added to the standard."

So I understand that DP_0_PIN13 should be connected pulled up to 3.3V. the question is how do I pick the resistor value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DP_0_PIN13 is pulled down by an 1M resistor. To effectively pull it up you need to raise it to at least 2V. The pull up and pull down resistors form a voltage divider. So anything less than 0.65M should do it.

I would go with a 470k resistor just to be sure.

Comment: Did you say at least 2V because for VCC = 2.7 V to 3.6 V the min(ViH)=2v?

Comment: Exactly! You can pull it harder if it doesn't work. Try 100k.